# Determinant of symmetric block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, determinant

I have a block matrix of the form:

$B = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
A_1 & C & \dots & C\\
\vdots & A_2 & \dots & C\\
C & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
C & C & C & A_N\\
\end{array} \right]$

where each $A_i$ and $C$ are $3 \times 3$ matrices. I would like to compute the determinant of such a matrix in terms of the matrices $A_i$ and $C$. The reason I would like to do this is, in part, because $C$ is very sparse (in fact $\det(C) = 0$). Is there any formula for doing this?

Comment: Here is a paper that allows one to express the determinant of a block matrix as a function of determinants of its blocks:http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4379

Comment: Do the $A_k, C$ have any other relationship?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Although the $C$ matrices have only one nonzero element (at $C_{3,3}$).

Comment: The matrix is not symmetric unless C and $A_i$ are symmetric. Assuming $a_i$ are symmetric, you should have $C^T$ on the superdiagonal elements in order for the matrix to be symmetric